# trying to get mod_rewrite to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this problem where I switched CMS from the old one to the new one so I am trying to redirect urls properly.

Here are some example urls I wanted to convert:

```
#-1) http://www.mysite.com/?dispatch=search_data&features=hash_tag
#-2) http://www.mysite.com/index.php?dispatch=search_data&features=hash_tag
```

Basically both of them are identical except the first one doesn't have index.php in the url.

I got the following to code to partially work:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dispatch=(.*)
 RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.com/? [L,R=301]
```

The above code works for #-1 (when there is no index.php) but when there is index.php it doesn't work.

Any help / guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks

__*_*__*_*__*_*___*UPDATE****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

As per request, here is what the the target url should be:
                       `http://www.mysite.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean it "works"?

You should probably post an example of what you want the new url to look like given the old url.

But in any case, part of your problem is that the `RewriteRule` line is specifically excluding `index.php` and any other page on your site.

What you wrote basically tranlates to this:

```
if the query string contains "dispatch=...":
    redirect requests FOR THE HOME PAGE ONLY (^$) to http://www.mysite.com/
```

Comment: I have updated the original post indicating what the target url should be. I am also not understanding why the destination url matters. I want both `?dispatch` and `index.php?dispatch` to be forwarded to `http://www.mysite.com`

Comment: I'm saying that `^$` only matches the base url (`/`) with nothing after it. Try `^(index\.php)?$` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dispatch=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ http://www.mysite.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. I worked with tangentstorm's code but yours was the same.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the second part to include the "index.php" part?

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.com/index.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I don't think that would be correct. Redirecting is not the issue here. The issue is that the rewrite condition doesn't work.